# How to Inject EJB3.1 session bean into JSF2.2 managed bean in JEE Enterprise application with Glassfish 4.0 server

Tags: jsf, cdi

I created a new Java EE 6 Enterprise-Application in Netbeans 7.4. So I have three Projects:

```
EAR
EJB
WAR
```

In order to implement the login functionality. I created the following.

1. In the EJB-Project, I have created a an entity bean(Useraccount) and stateless session Bean(UseraccoountManager) as follows:

Entity bean: Useraccount

```
package com.wms.entities;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@Table(name = "useraccount")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Useraccount.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM Useraccount u"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Useraccount.findById", query = "SELECT u FROM Useraccount u WHERE u.id = :id"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Useraccount.findByUsername", query = "SELECT u FROM Useraccount u WHERE u.username = :username"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Useraccount.findByPassword", query = "SELECT u FROM Useraccount u WHERE u.password = :password"),
@NamedQuery(name = "UserAccount.findUseraccount", query = "SELECT a FROM Useraccount a WHERE a.username = :username AND a.password = :password"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Useraccount.findByUserType", query = "SELECT u FROM Useraccount u WHERE u.userType = :userType")})
public class Useraccount implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 45)
@Column(name = "username")
private String username;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 45)
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "userType")
private String userType;

public Useraccount() {
}

public Useraccount(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Useraccount(Integer id, String username, String password) {
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getUserType() {
    return userType;
}

public void setUserType(String userType) {
    this.userType = userType;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Useraccount)) {
        return false;
    }
    Useraccount other = (Useraccount) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "com.wms.entities.Useraccount[ id=" + id + " ]";
}

}
```

Session bean: UseraccountManager

```
package com.wms.sessions;
import com.wms.entities.Useraccount;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

@Stateless

public class UseraccountManager implements UseraccountManagerRemote{
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public List<Useraccount> getAllUseraccount() {
    Query query=em.createNamedQuery("Useraccount.findAll");
    return query.getResultList();
}

public Useraccount update(Useraccount useraccount) {
    return em.merge(useraccount);
}
@Override
public void persist(Object object) {
    em.persist(object);
}

public Useraccount find(Useraccount useraccount){
   Query query=em.createNamedQuery("Useraccount.findByUsername").setParameter("username", useraccount.getUsername());
   List<Useraccount> acts=query.getResultList();
   if(acts.isEmpty()) 
            return null;
    Useraccount act=acts.get(0);
    if(!act.getPassword().equals(useraccount.getPassword()))
        return null;
    return act;
}
@Override
public String validateUser(String username, String password){
    System.out.println("\n\n\nheloooo\n\n\n");
    Query query=em.createNamedQuery("Useraccount.findByUsername").setParameter("username", username);
    List<Useraccount> acts=query.getResultList();
    if(acts.isEmpty()) 
            return "unknown";
    Useraccount act=acts.get(0);
    if(act.getPassword().equals(password))
        return act.getUserType();
    return "unknown";
}
}
```

2.In the Web application project, I created the Managed bean(LoginBean) and Login page(login.xhtml) as follows
Managed bean: LoginBean

```
package com.wms.managedbeans;

import com.wms.sessions.UseraccountManager;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@Named
@RequestScoped

public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String password;
private String message, username;
private String userType;
@EJB
private UseraccountManager uam;

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String uname) {
    this.username = uname;
}
public String getUser() {
    System.out.println(Util.getUserId());
    return Util.getUserId();
}
public String getUserType(){
    HttpSession session = Util.getSession();
    if ( session != null )
        return (String) session.getAttribute("userType");
    else
        return null;
}


public String login() {
     userType = uam.validateUser(username, password);
    HttpSession session = Util.getSession();
    if (userType.equals("unknown")){
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                null,
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,
                "Invalid Login!",
                "Please Try Again!"));
        // invalidate session, and redirect to other pages
        //message = "Invalid Login. Please Try Again!";
       return "login";
    }
    else{
      // get Http Session and store username
      session.setAttribute("username", username);
      session.setAttribute("userType",userType);
      if (userType.equals("administrator")) 
        return "admin/adminHome?faces-redirect=true";
      else if(userType.equals("warehouseman"))
        return "WM/wmHome?faces-redirect=true"; 
      else if(userType.equals("employee"))
        return "emp/empHome?faces-redirect=true"; 
      else 
          return "man/manHome?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}

public String logout() {
  HttpSession session = Util.getSession();
  session.invalidate();
  return "/login?faces-redirect=true";
}
}
```

User Interface: login.xhtml

```
<ui:composition template="/templates/layout.xhtml"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
 <ui:define name="content">
  <h:form styleClass="loginPanelStyle">
             <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" sticky="false" />                        
            <p:panelGrid columns="2">
            <f:facet name="header">
                Login Panel
            </f:facet>

            <h:outputText value="Username : "></h:outputText>
            <p:inputText id="username" value="#{loginBean.username}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please Enter Username!">
                <f:validateLength minimum="1" />  
            </p:inputText>
            <h:outputText value="Password : "></h:outputText>
            <p:password id="password" value="#{loginBean.password}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please Enter password!">
                <f:validateLength minimum="1" />  
            </p:password>
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton id="Submit" value="Submit" update="msgs" action="#{loginBean.login}" type="submit" icon="ui-icon-check" style="margin:0"></p:commandButton>
            </f:facet> 
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
 </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

After deploying the project when I run the web app it displays the login page, unforunately when i insert and  it generates the following error

```
WARNING:   /login.xhtml @16,131 value="#{loginBean.username}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'loginBean' resolved to null
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /login.xhtml @16,131 value="#{loginBean.username}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'loginBean' resolved to null
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.findImplicitConverter(InputRenderer.java:170)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.findConverter(InputRenderer.java:190)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.getConvertedValue(InputRenderer.java:196)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1046)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:976)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1249)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
at org.primefaces.component.layout.Layout.processValidators(Layout.java:246)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at filters.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:44)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'loginBean' resolved to null
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:174)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:86)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:201)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getType(WeldValueExpression.java:93)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:98)
... 51 more
```

I am new to EJB+JSF please help me to resolve the above problem

Comment: The problem seems to be that JSF cannot create an instance of `LoginBean`. Do you happen to have created the `beans.xml` file in your WEB-INF directory?

Comment: I added empty beans.xml, but it still come up with a new exception "FATAL:   JSF1073: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError caught during processing of RENDER_RESPONSE 6 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=Lcom/wms/sessions/UseraccountManager;
FATAL:   Lcom/wms/sessions/UseraccountManager;
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/wms/sessions/UseraccountManager;". I do not know if i have to configure something on the glassfish server or is something else

Comment: Now you have a different error. Note that it says: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/wms/sessions/UseraccountManager`. This means that your `UseraccountManager` class cannot be recognized. Recompile your code, make sure to add all the external libraries inside WEB-INF/lib folder, redeploy your application and try again.

Comment: When i recompile, deploy and run it the previous error in the original post came back again. BTW in this scenario do I need to have remote/local interface, if so please explain me how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I replace @Named annotation with @ManagedBean(name="loginBean") in the LoginBean managed bean class it works perfectly. But can any one explain me the difference between the two in this context. Thanks Luiggi Medoza for your help

Comment: just read this on https://weblogs.java.net/blog/mriem/archive/2013/10/30/jsf-tip-30-migrate-your-managedbean-named-annotations